# JPA - Check existence of value in another table as Boolean value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a (abbreviated) class that looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table
@SecondaryTable(
        name = "SUPER_ADMIN",
        pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(
                name = "PERSON_ID",
                referencedColumnName = "PERSON_ID"))
public class Person {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
  private Long personId;

  // getters/setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The `SUPER_ADMIN` table has only one column: `PERSON_ID`. What I would like to do is add `private Boolean superAdmin` to `Person` where it would be `true` if the `PERSON_ID` is present in that table.

Is this even possible? I am using Hibernate as my JPA provider, so I'm open to proprietary solutions as well.

### UPDATE

It seems like I should have done more homework. After poking around, I see that `@SecondaryTable` does *inner* joins and not *outer* joins. Therefore, my idea here will not work at all. Thanks to @Elbek for the answer -- it led me to this revelation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JPA callback methods.

```
public class Person {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
  private Long personId;

  @Transient
  private transient Boolean superAdmin = false;

  // This method will be called automatically when object is loaded
  @PostLoad
  void onPostLoad() { 
    // BTW, personId has to be present in the table since it is id column. Do you want to check if it is 1?
    superAdmin  =  personId == 1;  
  }
}
```

or you can create easy getter method.

```
public class Person {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
  private Long personId;

  boolean isSuperAdmin() { 
      return  personId == 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but I was looking for something more like the other JPA fields. Like if I set it to `true`, it would get persisted back, etc.

Comment: Do you want that field get persisted? Right now it won't be persisted.  if yes then you should use `@PreUpdate` or `@PrePersist` annotations to set the attribute value, so it will be set before being saved into DB. Also remove `transient` from the attr.

Comment: Went ahead and marked this as the correct answer, even though it doesn't solve my problem the way I wanted it to (it's unsolvable, see edit). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** have an **optional** relationship with a **@SecondaryTable**. You do not have any other choice than using a **@OneToOne** optional relationship in that case.